# How to enable the Java keyword assert in Eclipse program-wise?

Tags: java, eclipse, assert, assertions

How can I enable the `assert` keyword in Eclipse?

```
public class A
{
    public static void main(String ... args)
    {
        System.out.println(1);
        assert false;
        System.out.println(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The JVM takes argument `-enableassertions`, or `-ea`. Not sure where that is specified in Eclipse though.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

To be specific:

- Go to `Run->run configuration`
- select `java application` in left nav pan.
- right click and `select New`.
- select `Arguments` tab
- Add `-ea` in VM    arguments.

[image]

Comment: Thank u for detail explaination with picture

Comment: This had no effect for me.

Answer (score 49):

If anyone wants to **enable assertions by default** (in contrast to enabling them for just a single run configuration), it is possible with the following steps:

1. Window (menu bar)
2. Preferences
3. Java
4. Installed JREs
5. Select your JRE/JDK
6. Press Edit...
7. Default VM arguments
8. Add -ea

Comment: This is a very useful supplement; I can't believe I've been adding `-ea` to every run configuration (specifically while debugging) as assertions are such a handy, yet underused, feature during development.

Answer (score 9):

1. Form the menu bar, select `Run` -> `Run Configurations...`.
2. Select `Arguments` tab.
3. Add `-ea` to `VM arguments`.
4. Click `Apply`.
5. Click `Run`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to run configurations and add vm arguments as "-enableassertions" (or) "-ea"

After that when you run code with assert statement, you will see assert in action.

Comment: -enableassertions

Comment: @OhadKravchick you caught it after almost 5 years, ha ha. Updated answer. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

Java introduced the `assert` keyword, so the way to enable source-level support is to make sure that Eclipse's Java compliance level is 1.4 or higher.  (The chances are that the compliance level is already higher than that ...)

To cause a Java application launched from Eclipsed to run with assertion checking enabled, add the "-ea" argument to the VM arguments in the launcher configuration's "Arguments" tab.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone uses IDEA, `-ea` is enabled by default in some IDEA versions, but disabled in others. To manually configure it, it is under `run` -> `edit configuration` -> `vm option`