# java assert not throwing exception

Tags: java

I am checking if number is between 1-10 using assert, but if I enter a number beyond 10 it still gives me the result rather than throwing an exception. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class xina {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("enter any number");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num = input.nextInt();

        assert ( num >= 0 && num <= 10 ) : "bad number: " + num;
        System.out.println("You entered " + num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you enable assertions with `-ea`?

Answer (score 4):

Assertions are disabled by default in java. You need to manually enable them by adding `-ea` to your command-line arguments when you invoke the java compiler. I can't tell you how to do this without knowing what compiler/environment you're using.

Edit:

In eclipse, go to the `run` menu, and click on `run configurations`. Select the `arguments` tab and type `-ea` into the VM arguments.

Comment: @Nomad instructions added.

Answer (score 1):

Are assertions enabled (-ea flag when running program) ?

By default, they are not enabled by the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

This article shows you how to do it in eclipse. Could be helpful for you

- Go to Run->run configuration
- select java application in left nav pan.
- right click and select New.
- select Arguments tab
- Add -ea in VM arguments.

[How to enable the Java keyword assert in Eclipse program-wise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415160/how-to-enable-java-keyword-assert-in-eclipse-in-program-wise)