# Java - assert does not seem to be executed

Tags: java, assert

I do not understand why the output of this code is `-10`:

```
public class Prova {
    public void sip(int i){
        assert i>=0 : err();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    public int err(){
        ...
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Prova t = new Prova();
       t.sip(-10);
    }    
}
```

I thought assert would launch `err();`

Comment: You need to compile with `-ea`. I.E. assertions are an optional feature and need to be enabled at compile time.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was automatically enabled in net beans. <Shame on me>

Comment: @Boris-the-Spider: please make an answer from your comment, so the others can also benefit from your post. I would do it but it would be now stealing your ideas :)

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/11415160/2886891