# Java - How to view assert messages in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just been looking into assert in Java and now I am trying to figure out how can we view the message if the assert was true in Eclipse. Code below:

```
public class TheAssertClass {

    public TheAssertClass(){

        int y = 5;
        int x = 4;

        assert (y > x): "y is too big. y = " + y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TheAssertClass go = new TheAssertClass();

        System.out.println("The program ran");
    }

}
```

The console only displays "The program ran". I am not exactly sure if I am using this correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: You're supposed to assert things that are *supposed* to be true. Here you'd want to assert `y < x` to trigger an error.

Comment: But isn't y is greater than x (y>x) so it is true?

Comment: Yes, `y > x` is true, which is good. You are *asserting* that `y > x`. In effect, the `assert` statement says "if this is ever not true, end my program".

Comment: You aren't meant to see the assertion message if it passes. It would just be noise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable the Java keyword assert in Eclipse program-wise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415160/how-to-enable-the-java-keyword-assert-in-eclipse-program-wise)

Comment: hmmm not really a duplicate, I didn't know that I had to enable something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not have enabled assertions at the JVM level (with the -ea switch).
If you haven't, then this would explain the behaviour you are seeing. Try making the assertion false and see if anything appears on the console.

Also have a look at the following questions & answers for more detail:
* See [What does the "assert" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018683/what-does-assert-do)

Comment: Thanks I have enabled the vm arguments "-ea" in the run configuration in Eclipse and now it works.

Comment: However it thows an exception which is what I am suppose to get right? (if it returns false)

Comment: Maybe... I'll explain. It should throw an AssertionError (a subclass of Throwable) which would also give a stack trace. Exceptions are also subclasses of Throwable but are siblings of Errors. All derivatives of Throwable can contain stack traces. So I suspect you saw a stack trace and are therefore calling it an exception, whereas you in fact got an Assertion**Error**. If you got an AssertionError, then yes that is correct. If you got some other Exception then no, you something else has happened. What is the exception? So it depends on what you actually got, hence the 'Maybe'!

Answer (score 0):

Info on how to enable assertion in eclipse:

`Run -> Run Configuration -> Java Application -> Arguments (2nd tab) -> VM arguments -> -ea`

-ea = enable assertion.