# java's setColor results in illegal argument exception or assertions are skipped

Tags: java, exception, awt

I have this code (which is called from `paintComponent` in a class that inherits from `JPanel`.

```
    assert(red >= 0);
    assert(red <= 255);
    assert(green >= 0);
    assert(green <= 255);
    assert(blue >= 0);
    assert(blue <= 255);
    Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);
```

After some time I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color parameter outside of expected range: Red
    at java.awt.Color.testColorValueRange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Color.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Color.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at display.DrawCanvas.drawLed(DrawCanvas.java:55)
    at display.DrawCanvas.paintComponent(DrawCanvas.java:36)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
```

DrawCanvas.java:55 (line 55) is the last line in the code fragment above.

How is it possible that an argument is out of range while all values are between 0 and 255 (included)?

Comment: Are assertions enabled?  What is the `red` value?  Are any of `red`, `green`, or `blue` `float`?

Comment: I just checked indeed (I couldn't set a breakpoint but added extra code), and red has value 267 ... now checking how to enable assertions.

Comment: @rgettman if you make it as answer, I can accept it

Comment: [What does the Java assert keyword do, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2758224/5221149) TL;DR: Don't use `assert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java assertions aren't enabled by default.

- From the command line, pass the `-ea` command line flag to enable assertions.

  ```
  java -ea your.main.ClassHere
  ```
- From Eclipse, you'll have to go to your particular Run Configuration and add in `-ea` in your "VM Arguments" as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415160/how-to-enable-the-java-keyword-assert-in-eclipse-program-wise).
- From IntelliJ, it's similar.  In your particular Run Configuration, add in `-ea` in "VM options".

Regardless of your IDE, the goal is to get it to add `-ea` after `java` and before your main class name to enable assertions.

Once you've got assertions enabled, then they will stop your program with an `AssertionError` before you get the `IllegalArgumentException`.

This particular case will work since you've indicated in comments that the value is an `int` -- `267`.  Note that if you happen to have `float` values, then they could pass the assertions with invalid values that are greater than `1.0f` and less than or equal to `255.0f`.