# Assert statement is not throwing exception

Tags: java

Assert statement should throw a exception , right? 
but instead it prints print statement below. What might be the reason behind this? 
I also used Scanner class for this to check at runtime but it shows same result.

```
int number = 6;
assert number == 8;
System.out.println("print something");
```

Comment: you can refer to below link as to how to enable assertions in Eclipse IDE
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415160/how-to-enable-the-java-keyword-assert-in-eclipse-program-wise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assert are disabled unless you pass the `-ea` (*enable assertions*) command line option to the JVM.

For Eclipse, you may follow this link: [Setting execution arguments](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-executionArgs.htm)

Add `-ea` to the VM arguments:

> **VM Arguments**: Values meant to change the behavior of the Java virtual
>   machine (VM). For example, you may need to tell the VM whether to use
>   a just-in-time (JIT) compiler, or you may need to specify the maximum
>   heap size the VM should use. Refer to your VM's documentation for more
>   information about the available VM arguments.

Alternatively, this can be done widely on the JRE: [Adding a new JRE definition](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-add_new_jre.htm&cp=1_3_5_1)

> In the **Default VM Arguments** field, you can add/edit the default
>   arguments that will be passed to the VM when launching.