# How to use assert in Java to reject the non String argument?

Tags: java

I just start my Java learning in my first year of University. One problem requires "Note that `compareTo` accepts an `Object` as an argument, but you can reject non-`MyString` arguments using assert."

So how can I reject these non String argument?

`assert (object instanceof String)`?

Comment: You gave the answer yourself - try it out! But note: `object instanceof String` will also return `false` if `object` is `null`.

Comment: Also note that while assert works fine for this while it is turned on, it can be [turned off via an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415160/how-to-enable-the-java-keyword-assert-in-eclipse-program-wise) at runtime and should therefore not be used as the only form of parameter validation in production code. Real code should usually throw an `IllegalArgumentException` instead. But you'll probably hear about that later in your course.

Comment: You definitely want to talk to your instructor and ask him why they want you to use asserts, which have about zero relevance in real world java code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it like that:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
   assert other instanceof MyString;
   // other checks
}
```

But as suggested: This will also reject that case that your argument is `null`. Which you sometimes want to check. So better would be in my opinion:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
   if (other == null) {
     return false;
   }
   // other checks
}
```

Most modern IDE will even provide an `equals` method for you including the corresponding `hashCode`.

Comment: Thank you for your so fast reply!!! (I feel surprised that my question has been noticed by you.)

Comment: However, the question requires us Create a public class named MyString. MyString should provide a public constructor that accepts a single String argument. You should reject null Strings in your constructor using assert. and MyString should also implement the Java Comparable interface, returning 1 for a positive result and -1 for a negative result. Normally Strings are compared lexicographically: "aaa" comes before "z". MyString should compare instances based on the length of its stored String. So MyString("aaa") should come after MyString("z"), since "aaa" is longer than "z".

Comment: When I use assert second instanceof MyStirng; in my method public int compareTo(Object second), it still gives me the error message cannot find symbol