# Java assertions in IntelliJ IDEA Community?

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I enable assertions in IntelliJ?
My code compiles but the assertions do not show up anywhere on the output.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int someInt = 5;
    assert someInt > 5; 
    assert someInt <= 5; 
}
```

Comment: Can you please post an example of how you are using `assert` and where it is failing? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: one example: 

`    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int someInt = 5;

        assert someInt > 5;
        assert someInt <= 5;
    }`

this results in an empty console, no exceptions thrown

Comment: I ran your code in IntelliJ version 2020.3 and JDK 8. I do not see the assertions in the IntelliJ console either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Based on this answer for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415160/how-to-enable-the-java-keyword-assert-in-eclipse-program-wise) you need to pass a JVM option `-ea` to enable assertions in *any* JVM. It's not unique to any specific IDE.

For IntelliJ it looks like this in the run config:
[image: IntelliJ 2020.3 Run Dialog to enter ea option]

Note that you may have to select "Modify Options" to make the JVM options input box visible to enter the `-ea` flag.